# Android Studio AsyncHttpClient Post Request not working REST

Tags: android, android-asynctask, androidhttpclient, android-async-http

I am creating an app in Android Studio. I am trying to send 5 parameters to a database through a rest service I have previously configured. I have tested the webpage through a browser plugin and a post request and is working fine, so I know for sure the problem is from the app itself. I also made sure the data I was sending was also good(locationX, locationY, time, date, username). Does anyone have any idea why this isnt working?

```
public void onClickSendCoordinates(View v)
{
    final EditText textbox3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textbox3);

    String date = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
    String time = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    String url = "http://somewebsite.com/index.php";
    String locationX = textbox2.getText().toString();
    String locationY = textbox1.getText().toString();
    String username = "user_1";

    EditText textbox4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textbox4);
    textbox4.setText(username + locationX + locationY + date + time);
    AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("locationX", locationX);
    params.put("locationY", locationY);
    params.put("date", date);
    params.put("time", time);

    httpClient.post(url, params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res) {
            //called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
            textbox3.setText("Success");
          //  Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Sending URL " + url + "with params " + params.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res, Throwable t) {
            textbox3.setText("Failure");
          //  Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Sending URL " + url + "with params " + params.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            //called when response HTTP status is "4xx" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is the exact issue? Is your server receiving the call? or the call itself is not happening?

Comment: HttpClient is deprecated, please use HttpUrlConnection.

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient is **deprecated in 23**. Please use HttpURLConnnection.

```
// HTTP GET request

public String sendGet(String apiUrl) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

For HTTP POST

```
  // HTTP POST request
public String sendPost(String apiurl, String args) {
    String response = "";
    try {
        URL url= new URL(apiurl);;
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        DataOutputStream printout;
        DataInputStream input;
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.connect();
        printout = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        byte[] data=args.getBytes("UTF-8");
        printout.write(data);
        printout.flush();
        printout.close();

        int responseCode =conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
        } else {
            response = "";

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```